# java -version コマンドがスーパーユーザでない場合使えない

Tags: java, macos

javaのバージョンを確認するコマンド

```
java --version
```

をターミナルで入力する際、admin権限のアカウントであっても先頭にsudoと入力しないと何も起こりません。

また他にもprotractorを使う際にもコマンド入力すると同様の現象になるのですが、何か解決方法はないでしょうか。

**OS INFO**

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.3
```

**/usr/bin/ にて ls -laをした結果(Adminとゲストユーザー共に同じ)**

```
(java)
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         74 Feb 18 13:31 java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
(javac)
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         75 Feb 18 13:31 javac -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac
```

**which java 実行結果**

```
/usr/bin/java
```

**type java 実行結果**

```
java is hashed (/usr/bin/java)
```

**/usr/bin/java -version 実行結果**

```
待機状態のままなにも表示されず。次のコマンドを打つためにはCtrl＋Cで停止させる必要有
```

ちなみにゲストユーザーで試したところ sudo無しでも問題なくバージョンが表示されました。

Comment: `which java` と `type java` と `/usr/bin/java -version` の実行を試してみて下さい。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。実行結果を反映させました。

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`を実行するとなんて出ますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。強硬手段として昨夜 `sudo vidudo`をした後に自分の`whoami`で出るユーザーを`ユーザー名 ALL=(ALL) ALL`と追加して保存した所sudo無しで使えるようになったのですが、今日試しに追加した行をコメントアウトして`java -version`を実行したら理由はよくわかりませんがバージョンが表示されました…。何がどう原因だったのかわかりませんが

Comment: とりあえず直ったので解決ということにします。協力していただいた方々に感謝です。

Answer (score 1):

強硬手段として、`sudo visudo` をした後に自分の `whoami` で表示されるユーザー名を以下の様に追加して保存しました。

```
ユーザー名 ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

上記の設定後に `sudo` 無しで使えるようになったのですが、後日試しに追加した行をコメントアウトして `java -version` を実行したら、理由はよくわかりませんがバージョンが表示されました。
何がどう原因だったのかわかりませんが

---

*この投稿は [@ynbenson さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35835/java-version-%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%81%8c%e3%82%b9%e3%83%bc%e3%83%91%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a6%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b6%e3%81%a7%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%88%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment35621_35835) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*